# How to install magento extensions from behind an ISA Server?

Tags: windows-server-2003, isa-server, magento

I am trying to install some Magento extensions however it keeps timing out. When I run a trace through ISA Server 2004 I can't see any denied traffic. The only thing I do get is a http proxy closed status:

> A connection was abortively closed
>   after one of the peers sent a RST
>   segment.

I can't tell what I need to open as both HTTP and HTTPS are allowed.

Cheers

Comment: This is about http://www.magentocommerce.com/. Stooie try putting a 'Magento' tag on this.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what "magento extensions" are, but if you're having problems communicating with the Internet on a host behind a firewall, regardless of the type of firewall, I'd recommend firing up a sniffer on the host and watching the outbound traffic. It's a lot easier, to me, than trying to grub around in firewall logs figuring out what's getting dropped. Wireshark, tcpdump, Network Monitor, etc, are your friends for this.

Comment: Seems to be this: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect  MAGENTO - not MAGNETO :)

Comment: Problem is that it works no problem when connected to the internet. As soon as you connect to the LAN and behind ISA it fails.

Comment: My opinion stands: You need to sniff the traffic and see what the application is trying to do. Anything else is just random speculation.

Comment: HI,

I have ran wireshark as I have tried to install the extension. It is trying to connect to connect.magentocommerce.com (208.69.123.164) on port 80. All of which is open on the firewall. the second packet is a ICMP Destination unreachable.

Comment: You're getting an ICMP destination unreachable from where? Does the TCP connection to 208.69.123.164 ever actually get started (i.e. you see the SYN from your box to the 208.x.x.x address, a SYN-ACK coming back from the 208.x.x.x address, and an ACK from your box back to the 208.x.x.x address)?

Comment: It is from 208.69.123.164 (magento) I do see a syn from the pc but it is then imeadiatly followed by the ICMP destination unreachable.

Comment: That sure sounds like your firewall is closing the TCP connection (by spoofing the source address of the 208.x.x.x server). Can you browse web sites on this machine? I'm guessing not. You're probably going to need to have the ISA client installed on that machine or you're going to need to manually specify an HTTP proxy and credentials.

Comment: I have tried with the fw client and i can broswe the web from the machine no problem. I realy am pulling my hair out

Comment: So, you can access web sites. What happens when you try to access the URL that the magento software is accessing with a browser? What security context is the magento software running as?

Comment: HTTP and I can browse to the site although it does re-direct my session to the home page.

Comment: Just plugged the laptop direct into the internet and it works so it is defiantly something to do with the firewals. :( Thanks for the help BTW

Comment: We're getting quite the convo going here, eh?  What security context is the software using when it tries to hit this URL? Is this some program running as a service? My guess is that the firewall has rules based on who the user is performing the access, and you're running the installation program from the SYSTEM context or such, which isn't being permitted access. Alternatively, it could be that your browser is using an HTTP proxy but the installlation software isn't.

Comment: It doesn't run as a service. Basicaly you add a link in to the website which then contacts magento to download the extension. We are using ISA 2004 as a proxy server but I can't see why the program can't communicate through it.

Answer (score 1):

to download updates using magento connect behind a proxy

you will have to edit file:
/downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/curl.php

and after the line
$this->_ch = curl_init();

you will need to add

```
$this->curlOption(CURLOPT_PROXY, “YourProxy:YourProxyPort");
$this->curlOption(CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, “YourUser:YourPassword"); // if needed
```